# Autoencoder learns average of all samples

Tags: java, neural-network, processing, autoencoder

I'm a programming enthusiast learning how to write an autoencoder from scratch.
I've already tried making simple neural networks for linear regression problems and non-linear data classification, so I figured this wouldn't be as hard.
I got to the point where my autoencoder learns it's best, but the output is average of all inputs like these two:

[image]
[image]

And here's the output:

[image]

If you want to see a video of it training, it's here:
https://youtu.be/w8mPVj_lQWI

If I add all other 17 samples (another batch of digits 1 and 2), it becomes a smear, average looking result too:

[image]

I designed my network to be 3 layers, with 64 input neurons (input is a 4096-dimensional vector, referring to a 64x64 image sample), 8 neurons in the bottleneck part (second layer), and outputing 4096 neurons, each one for one dimension of the final output.

I'm using tanh as my activation function (except in the last layer, which uses linear activation) and backpropagation as a learning algorythm, calculating partial derivatives from the output layer neurons, back to the input ones.

In the upper-left corner is the input image and in the middle is the output image. All values range from -1 to 1 (because of the tanh activation), where 1 means white, 0 and below means black.

The output image is generated after arround 12k epochs of 2 images, that is at learning rate of 5*10-e6.

One interesting discovery is, that if I increase learning rate to 0.001, the output becomes clearly either a 1 or 2, but in wrong order. Take a look at this video: https://youtu.be/LyugJx8RiJ8

I can try training on a 5 layer neural network, but it does the same thing.

Can you think of any problems the code I've written could have. I didn't use any pre-made libraries, everything from scratch, reading pixels and stuff.
Here's my code in Processing if it helps (although it's a lot and a bit messy):

```
class Nevron{

    public double w[];
    public double a;
    public double z;
    public double b;
    public double der;
    public double derW;
    public double derB;
    public double lr = 0.00001;

    public Nevron(int stVhodov){
      w = new double[stVhodov];
      a = 0;
      z = 0;
      der = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < w.length; i++){
        w[i] = random(-1, 1);
      }
      b = random(-1, 1);
    }

    public void answer(double []x){
      a = 0;
      z = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        z = z + x[i]*w[i];
      }
      z += b;
      a = Math.tanh(z);
    }


    public void answer(layer l){
      a = 0;
      z = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < l.nevron.length; i++){
          z = z + l.nevron[i].a*w[i];
      }
      z += b;
      a = Math.tanh(z);
    }

    public void answerOut(layer l){
      a = 0;
      z = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < l.nevron.length; i++){
          z = z + l.nevron[i].a*w[i];
      }
      z += b;
      a = z;
    }

    public void changeWeight(layer l){
      for(int i = 0; i < l.nevron.length; i++){
        w[i] = w[i] - der * lr * l.nevron[i].a;
        b = b - der * lr;
      }
      der = 0;
    }

    public void changeWeight(double []x){
      for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        w[i] = w[i] - der * lr * x[i];
        b = b - der * lr;
      }
      der = 0;
    }

    public double MSE(double odg){
      return (odg-a)*(odg-a);
    }

    public double derOut(double odg, double wl){
      der = 2*(a-odg);
      return 2*(a-odg)* wl;
    }

    public double derHid(double wl){
      return der * (1-Math.pow(Math.tanh(z), 2)) * wl;
    }
  }

  class layer{

    public Nevron nevron[];

    public layer(int stNevronov, int stVhodov){
      nevron = new Nevron[stNevronov];
      for(int i = 0; i < stNevronov; i++){
        nevron[i] = new Nevron(stVhodov);
      }
    }
    public void answer(double []x){
      for(int i = 0; i < nevron.length; i++){
        nevron[i].answer(x);
      }
    }
    public void answer(layer l){
      for(int i = 0; i < nevron.length; i++){
        nevron[i].answer(l);
      }
    }

    public void answerOut(layer l){
      for(int i = 0; i < nevron.length; i++){
        nevron[i].answerOut(l);
      }
    }

    public double[] allanswers(){
      double answerOut[] = new double[nevron.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < nevron.length; i++){
        answerOut[i] = nevron[i].a;
      }
      return answerOut;
    }

  }

  class Perceptron{

    public layer layer[];
    public double mse = 0;

    public Perceptron(int stVhodov, int []layeri){
      layer = new layer[layeri.length];
      layer[0] = new layer(layeri[0], stVhodov);
      for(int i = 1; i < layeri.length; i++){
        layer[i] = new layer(layeri[i], layeri[i-1]);
      }
    }
    public double [] answer(double []x){
      layer[0].answer(x);
      for(int i = 1; i < layer.length-1; i++){
        layer[i].answer(layer[i-1]);
      }
      layer[layer.length-1].answerOut(layer[layer.length-2]);
      return layer[layer.length-1].allanswers();
    }

    public void backprop(double ans[]){
      mse = 0;
      //hid-out calculate derivatives
      for(int i = 0; i < layer[layer.length-1].nevron.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < layer[layer.length-2].nevron.length; j++){
          layer[layer.length-2].nevron[j].der += layer[layer.length-1].nevron[i].derOut(ans[i], layer[layer.length-1].nevron[i].w[j]);
          mse += layer[layer.length-1].nevron[i].MSE(ans[i]);
        }
      }
      //hid - hid && inp - hid calculate derivatives
      //println(mse);
      for(int i = layer.length-2; i > 0; i--){
        for(int j = 0; j < layer[i].nevron.length-1; j++){
          for(int k = 0; k < layer[i-1].nevron.length; k++){
            layer[i-1].nevron[k].der += layer[i].nevron[j].derHid(layer[i].nevron[j].w[k]);
          }
        }
      }
      //hid-out change weights
      for(int i = layer.length-1; i > 0; i--){
        for(int j = 0; j < layer[i].nevron.length; j++){
          layer[i].nevron[j].changeWeight(layer[i-1]);
        }
      }
      //hid-out change weights
      for(int i = 0; i < layer[0].nevron.length; i++){
        layer[0].nevron[i].changeWeight(ans);
      }

    }

  }
```

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about your output, shouldn't each input image have its own output image?

Comment: It is an image, although it seems it combined both images for some reason. You can see in the top left corner the input image. In the middle it's the output.

Comment: Each input image should have it's own output image. Do you have two input images? You should have two output images.

Comment: Yes, I do, but above I showed you only the output for the second image, which is the same as for the first - they look identical, but they are different outputs.

Comment: Since the code seems to be working I'd assume this belongs to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. If the code doesn't work then you might want to state your question/problem more clearly. :)

Comment: Aha, thanks Thomas for mentioning it. I've never hear of it before. I'll try posting the code there

Comment: You could also include some of the training parameters. How many training images did you use, how many epochs etc. It is possible your network has found a local minimum and has trouble getting out of it. Plus, can you compare the outputs for the two images, exactly. As in, does the output differ at all, but it isn't very perceivable. If it is exact, it sounds like you might need to fix the initialization of your network.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that to the post

Comment: About local minimums, how do you get the best one? What are the techniques for finding the one closest to 0?

Comment: If you are seeing the output is in the wrong order, make sure your training data is aligned. If the training data doesn't correspond properly, the minimum will be a single image that can minimize the error for all of the images... eg the mean.

Comment: Also, a larger learning rate can cause the network to be jostled out of a local minima. In regards to how do you get the best one; that is one of the main questions in neural networks.

Comment: I'm doing some more testing and it looks like it just needs more time. I'll mark this question as solved once I ensure training time was the cause.
At first it looks like it stopped learning when the image of 2 mixed letters was generated. But in fact, after checking the loss, I noticed, that after a few minutes it started dropping again. It also fixed the problem of generating the wrong digit image.

Comment: Luck plays and important role here; sometimes you get a good run and the results are nice. Take a look at this example: https://youtu.be/EM6ii-hvxhg
I switched digits with people's faces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I spent most of my time figuring out the best combination of parameters and found out:

- Don't rush, take your time and see how the NN is progressing
- Watch the loss, how it descends, if it bounces back and forth, lower learn rate or try running the NN again (because of local minima)
- Start with 2 samples and see, how many neurons do you need in the bottleneck layer. Try using images of circles and squares as training data
- It takes NN longer to differentiate similar images
- then try taking 3 samples and see the best combination of neurons and layers.

All in all, most of it is luck based (though you still have good chances of getting a good training session on the third try), that is if you're implementing it from scratch. I'm sure there are other methods, that help the NN jump out of local minima, different gradient descents and so on.
Here are my final results of an autoencoder (5 layers with 16, 8, 8, 16, 4096 neurons), that can encode faces of Ariana Grande, Tom Cruise and Sabre Norris (source: famousbirthdays.com). The upper images are of course reconstructions my decoder generated.

[image][image][image]

I also made a simple editor, where you can mess with decoder's inputs and managed to make Stephen Fry's face:

[image]

Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Then my solution to it was actually quite simple. Normalize your dataset with respect to the functions, e.g if sigmoid , scale the input data to the range (1 and 0.) That will automatically solve your problem. For example,

```
input = (1/255) * pixel_image_value
```

Here the pixel_image_value is in the range 0 -255, then after you get your output x_hat , scale it back before displaying as image by

```
output_pixel_value  = 255 * sigmoid_ouput_value
```